# Update multiple rows only if all of them exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, go-pg

I'd like to update multiple rows only if all of them exist in the database, how this could be done?

In this case if any of books don't exist it doesn't stop the other one to be updated.

`books` table looks as follow:

```
id PK
title VARCHAR
```

Let's say we have just one book stored in the database:

```
id: 1
title: "A simple title"
```

If I want update 2 books and one of them isn't stored in the database I'd like to cancel whole update process - leave the table without any changes.

Below query should update nothing:

```
UPDATE "books" AS "book"
SET "title" = _data."title"
FROM (VALUES ('updated book 1', 1), ('updated book 2', 2)) AS _data("title", "id")
WHERE "book"."id" = _data."id"
```

Is it possible to achieve that without using transaction?

Thanks from advance for help!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see.  How about counting the matches first?

```
WITH bb as (
      SELECT v.*
      FROM (VALUES ('updated book 1', 1),
                   ('updated book 2', 2)
           ) v(title, id) 
     )
UPDATE books b
    SET title = b.title
    FROM bb CROSS JOIN
         (select count(*) as cnt, count(b.id) as b_cnt
          from bb left join
               books b
               using (id)
         ) bb
     WHERE bb.id = b.id AND
           bb.cnt = b.b_cnt;
```

Notice that I removed all those pesky double quotes.  Quoted identifiers are not a good idea.